# Trying to checkout to a previous commit ID. I get the results: "warning: unable to rmdir"

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

My teammates on Github had been working on a repository. My job is simply to go back to previous commits and see all the submodules.

So far I downloaded the repository to my computer.

I'm applying git checkout to a previous commit ID and get the following at the start:

```
git checkout 20e8984854d21dcd78d7bc424d4d12f2c40ba943d
warning: unable to rmdir (directory): Directory not empty
warning: unable to rmdir (directory): Directory not empty
warning: unable to rmdir (directory): Directory not empty
warning: unable to rmdir (directory): Directory not empty
Updating files: 100% (6230/6230), done.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215094/git-bash-giving-error-of-warning-unable-to-rmdir

Comment: phd, they explain the problem but not sure how can I solve it? I applied the solution from the second answer and it's still not working unfortunately.

Comment: 1. Remove temporary files before checkout. 2. These are only warnings, checkout and then remove extra directories.